# VBA/AutoLisp - How to check if a block is grouped through code in AutoCAD

Tags: vba, grouping, autocad, autolisp

I am working with groups in AutoCAD and, due to copy pasting them from different drawings, they ungroup. 
In the possibility of me forgetting to regroup them, I want to create a code that, when I think I am finished with the drawing, can check if a list of blocks (every group has a block) is not inside a group.

As such, the idea is that it would run from a selection of blocks (ex: block1, block3, block7) and check if those particular blocks are grouped. If not, it would tell me which block is ungrouped.

As the tags suggest, either vba or autolisp is fine. I am fairly novice at this, any help would be fairly appreciated.

edit: knowing how I could get a block group name in vba would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Background

A block **definition** may have many block **references**: the block definition is analogous to the blueprints for a building, with each block reference analogous to the construction of the building itself.

As such, given only a list of block **names**, each block name may correspond to multiple block **references**, with some contained within groups, and others not.

---

#### Methods

You can therefore approach this task from two angles:

- Iterate over all **Groups** defined within the drawing (either using the ActiveX Groups Collection, or the `ACAD_GROUP` dictionary contained within the Named Object Dictionary), and obtain the set of distinct block names corresponding to blocks contained within at least one Group.

<sup>OR</sup>

- Iterate over all **Block References** within the drawing and test whether the block reference has a link to a `GROUP` entity via an `{ACAD_REACTORS}` entry in the DXF data. Compile a list of block names corresponding to blocks which are either contained within at least one group, or not contained within any group.

Given such a list, you can then easily test whether any of your block names are not present in the list.

---

#### Sample Code

Below is a function that will iterate over all Groups defined within the `ACAD_GROUP` dictionary of the Named Object Dictionary, and will return a list of the names of block references contained within one or more groups:

```lisp
(defun blocknamesfromgroups ( / blk dic enx grp rtn )
    (if (setq dic (cdr (assoc -1 (dictsearch (namedobjdict) "acad_group"))))
        (while (setq grp (dictnext dic (not grp)))
            (foreach itm grp
                (if (and (= 340 (car itm)) (= "INSERT" (cdr (assoc 0 (setq enx (entget (cdr itm)))))))
                    (if (not (member (setq blk (cdr (assoc 2 enx))) rtn))
                        (setq rtn (cons blk rtn))
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
    (reverse rtn)
)
```

Alternatively, the below function will iterate over all primary block references in the active drawing and will report the names of block references not contained within a group:

```lisp
(defun blocknamesnotgrouped ( / blk enx grp idx sel rtn )
    (if (setq sel (ssget "_X" '((0 . "INSERT"))))
        (repeat (setq idx (sslength sel))
            (setq idx (1- idx)
                  enx (entget (ssname sel idx))
                  blk (cdr (assoc 2 enx))
            )
            (if
                (not
                    (or
                        (and
                            (setq enx  (member '(102 . "{ACAD_REACTORS") enx))
                            (setq grp  (cdr (assoc 330 enx)))
                            (= "GROUP" (cdr (assoc 0 (entget grp))))
                        )
                        (member blk rtn)
                    )
                )
                (setq rtn (cons blk rtn))
            )
        )
    )
    (reverse rtn)
)
```

Comment: thank you very much, worked like a charm. I slightly changed it so it filters the blocks that I wanted to see if were grouped or not:
`(if (setq sel (ssget "_X" '((0 . "INSERT") (2 . "BLOCK1,BLOCK2,BLOCK3"))))`
I am giving you the answer, although I have a tangent that I would love if you could explain me why is it not working. I want to delete the blocks that are ungrouped, and as such i used
`(command "erase" blk "")`
What am I not getting right?

Comment: You're most welcome Pedro. The supplied functions will return a list of block names; if you wish to erase the blocks that are ungrouped, you will need to use the second function and instead of obtaining the block name, you should use `entdel` with the block reference entity (DXF group -1 or the entity returned by the `ssname` function).